# SPWeb.Url returns wrong URL

Tags: sharepoint, spweb, spcontext, alternate-access-mappings

I have a web application in SharePoint that has been extended to another zone (Extranet). The access URL for the default zone is http ://server1, and the URL for the extranet zone is https: //www.server1.com.

Now, when I access the site via the extranet zone, I find that SPContext.Current.Web.Url returns http ://server1. I would have expected https ://www.server1.com, since that's how I'm accessing the site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's interesting - I have an alternate access mapping on a different port (`http://example` vs `http://example:8387`) and SPContext.Web.Url performs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
SPContext.Current.Site.MakeFullUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl);
```

That should take into account your access mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Odd...

As an alternative, have you tried using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url ?